# Passing javascript variable to Paypal

Tags: javascript, variables, paypal, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable amount (this being the total order value) to the 'amount' variable in a paypal form. However, the value is generated from a drop down list. I've scoured the forums and tried a few things, but can't find what I thought would be a simple solution.

Below is the code.

As you can see there are a couple of options I have tried, but neither pass the variable selected from the drop down list.

I appreciate the issues with Paypal security... but that aside, is there anyone with a much larger brain than mine who can spot an obvious solution.

Thanks!!

Andy

PS If I change the var 'andy' to, say, 33, it all works fine.

```
<label for="CurrentExcess">Current Excess (£100 - £500 Max.)</label>

<select id="dropdown"> 
  <option value="invalid entry">please select</option>
  <option value="12">£100</option>
  <option value="18">£150</option>
  <option value="24">£200</option>
  <option value="30">£250</option>
  <option value="36">£300</option>
  <option value="42">£350</option>
  <option value="48">£400</option>
  <option value="54">£450</option>
  <option value="60">£500</option>
  <option value="all us to discuss">more then £500</option>
</select> 


        </div>
        <div>
<label for="price">Your membership fee will be: £</label>
<input type="text" name="price" value="" id="mytext" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext'); 
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown'); 
mydropdown.onchange = function(){ 
      mytextbox.value = this.value; 
} 
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mytext;
var andy = mytext
</script>


<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@me.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Title">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="11">
<!-- <script> 
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="amount" value='+andy+'>'); 
</script> -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="finalpaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the input from sdleihssirhc. That does help, but as I am a bit of a duffer with javascript am still struggling.

The bit I didn't emphasise is that I am trying to get the value from 'mytext' into 'amount' which is passed to paypal. And I dont care how, but it seems that as the value is calculated with an 'OnChange'....it all goes a bit bonkers.

The main bits of code now read as below on last bit of post.

**ANY BRIGHT IDEAS ANYONE. MANY THANKS!!!!**

```
<label for="CurrentExcess">Current Excess (£100 - £500 Max.)</label>

<select id="dropdown"> 
  <option value="invalid entry">please select</option>
  <option value="12">£100</option>
  <option value="18">£150</option>
  <option value="24">£200</option>
  <option value="30">£250</option>
  <option value="36">£300</option>
  <option value="42">£350</option>
  <option value="48">£400</option>
  <option value="54">£450</option>
  <option value="60">£500</option>
  <option value="all us to discuss">more then £500</option>
</select> 


        </div>
        <div>
<label for="price">Your membership fee will be: £</label>
<input type="text" name="price" value="" id="mytext" />
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@me.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Title">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="11">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="finalpaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

</form>

<script> 
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');  
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');  
var finalpaypal = document.getElementById('finalpaypal'); 
mydropdown.onchange = function(){  
mytextbox.value = this.value; 
finalpaypal.value = this.value; 
}  
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mytext; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is with the your HTML - JavaScript - HTML ordering. You have this line in your JS...

```
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mytext.value;
```

...But the element with the ID "finalpaypal" doesn't exist, yet. Can you move the `<script>` to the bottom of the page, after all of the form's HTML?

The second problem is also with that line. You're trying to set the input's value to a variable that (as far as I can tell) doesn't actually exist. If you want the value to be the same as what you set the textbox to, just do this:

```
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mytextbox.value;
```

But then we get to the last problem: You should put this line inside the event handler.

So the final code will look like this:

```
<!-- all of the form's HTML -->

<script>
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext'); 
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown'); 
var finalpaypal = document.getElementById('finalpaypal');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){ 
    mytextbox.value = this.value;
    finalpaypal.value = this.value;
} 
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mytext;
</script>
```

Comment: sorry man, i clicked the wrong one to edit and it thought it was my post

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED MY FIRST POST. ANYONE WHO HAS A BRIGHT IDEA ABOUT HOW TO PASS A VARIABLE SELECTED FROM A DROP DOWN LIST WITH AN ONCHANGE COMMAND - TO PASS TO THE 'AMOUNT' AREA OF A PAYPAL SUBMISSION....I WOULD BE EVER SO GRATEFUL!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `select` tag you have to include it in your paypal button form. You have to use the `on0` and `os0` tags.

You can read more about it here: [click here](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

and you can see examples here: [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paypal_shopping_cart/#id08AEC03L05H)

and a jsfiddle example for you [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/9nP9S/)

```
<div>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@me.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Title">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="11">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<!-- Here are your select options-->
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="prices">
<select name="os0"> 
<option value="please select">please select</option>
<option value="12">£100</option>
<option value="18">£150</option>
<option value="24">£200</option>
<option value="30">£250</option>
<option value="36">£300</option>
<option value="42">£350</option>
<option value="48">£400</option>
<option value="54">£450</option>
<option value="60">£500</option>
</select>  
<!-- This is how paypal will get the prices from your options menu-->
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="18">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="150">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="24">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="200">
<!--etc...-->

<!-- Here is the button -->
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now">
```